# Передача аргумента в цепочке из функций

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы, prototype, this

Мы работаем с API, и чтобы удобно получать и обрабатывать данные, реализовали следующее: создали функцию, которая возвращает объект с методами. Из этого мы можем получить цепочку функций. Но у нас возникла проблема, что нам нужна еще одна функция вложенная в первый метод, которая будет работать с данными, полученными из родительской функции. Как лучше это реализовать? 
Либо предложите иной способ реализации, пожалуйста.

Описательная часть, чего мы хотим добиться:

```js
function f() {
  return {
    method1: function() {
      return {
        returnData: function() {
          return something1
        },

        method3: function(method) {
          // Производятся манипуляция с результатами работы returnData.
        }
      };
    },

    method2: function() {
      return something2;
    }
  }
}

let example = f();

let x = example.method1();

// Принимает в качестве аргументов method2.returnData().
let y = example.method2().method3( /* returnData */ );

// Возвращает обычные данные.
y = example.method2().returnData();
```

И наш уже рабочий код с двумя методами, без третьего:

```js
let arrManagers = [];

let getElements = function(manager) {
  let responsive;

  return {
    getLeads: async function() {
      responsive = await fetch(`/api/v2/leads?responsible_user_id=${manager}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    },

    getContacts: async function() {
      responsive = await fetch(`/api/v2/contacts?responsible_user_id=${manager}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос давно исчерпан, привести код не смог.
Всё разрешилось на том, что мы в методе возвращали текущий объект:

```
return this;
```

И в методах просто обрабатывали информацию об объекте. Промежуточно, мы сохраняли информацию в переменной, а потом в другом методе, который вызывался в цепочке, обрабатывали

```
this
```

и все переменные.